# Is it possible to have app level routes take precedence over plugin level routes in Symfony 1.4?

Tags: routes, symfony-1.4

I'm developing a Symfony 1.4 plugin and I noticed that plugin routes get matched before app level routes. Is it possible to have app level routes evaluated first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin routes are designed to overwrite app level routes, this is a feature.

I would suggest this is probably an issue with the design of your plugin.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to integrate some existing code with Symfony. I found a better way, thanks for your response.